# Applying lm with map2

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, purrr

I'm trying to learn `purrr`'s map functions by using `map2` to apply `lm`. Using a subset of the `mtcars` data set, I create a data frame with combinations of the variables' names, like this:

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Subset data
df <- mtcars %>% select(mpg:qsec) 

# Get variable names
car_vars <- colnames(df)

# Create data frame of variable names
foo <- combn(car_vars, 2) %>% t %>% data.frame

# > head(foo)
#    X1   X2
# 1 mpg  cyl
# 2 mpg disp
# 3 mpg   hp
# 4 mpg drat
# 5 mpg   wt
# 6 mpg qsec
```

Next, I have a function that takes the name of two variables and fits a linear model:

```
# Fit model
fit_lm <- function(c1, c2){
  lm(paste(c1, c2, sep = "~"), data = df)
}
```

I can apply this with `map2` like so:

```
# Fit all the models 
map2(foo$X1, foo$X2, fit_lm)
```

giving a list of `lm` objects that looks something like this when printed:

```
# [[1]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = paste(c1, c2, sep = "~"), data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl  
# 37.885       -2.876
```

Great! Now, here's where I stumble. I'd like to add these `lm` objects as a column in my data frame, so I conveniently have the variable names in the same row as the model itself. So, I use `dplyr`'s `mutate` with `map2`.

```
# Not so successful
foo %>% mutate(mods = map2(X1, X2, fit_lm))
```

The `mods` column produced has class NULL rather than `lm` and looks a bit like a `dput` of a `lm` object, unlike my previous (successful) attempt. Clearly, I've misunderstood how `map2` works. Can someone explain my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of the result itself, what you did is fine:

```
foo <- foo %>% mutate(mods = map2(X1, X2, fit_lm))
str(foo, max.level = 1)
# 'data.frame': 21 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ X1  : Factor w/ 6 levels "cyl","disp","drat",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ X2  : Factor w/ 6 levels "cyl","disp","drat",..: 1 2 4 3 6 5 2 4 3 6 ...
#  $ mods:List of 21
```

The problem is simply that

```
class(foo)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

and such complex lists as those of `lm` class are printed terribly with `print.data.frame`. So, as to instead see the result nicely with `print.tbl`, we only need to convert `foo` to `tibble`:

```
foo <- as.tbl(foo)
foo
# A tibble: 21 x 3
#    X1    X2    mods    
#    <fct> <fct> <list>  
#  1 mpg   cyl   <S3: lm>
#  2 mpg   disp  <S3: lm>
#  3 mpg   hp    <S3: lm>
#  4 mpg   drat  <S3: lm>
#  5 mpg   wt    <S3: lm>
#  6 mpg   qsec  <S3: lm>
#  7 cyl   disp  <S3: lm>
#  8 cyl   hp    <S3: lm>
#  9 cyl   drat  <S3: lm>
# 10 cyl   wt    <S3: lm>
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Whoa! Why does `foo` need to be a `tibble`?

Comment: @Lyngbakr, I added a proper explanation.